# Creating a Castle Windsor Controller Factory and GetControllerInstance is never called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I am introducing DI into my MS MVC application and I am having trouble getting the controllers instantiated from within my custom Controller Factory. It seems that the overridden "GetControllerInstance" is not being called.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

My Controller Factory:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
        var controllerTypes =
            from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
            select t;
        foreach (var t in controllerTypes)
            container.Register(Component.For(t).LifeStyle.Transient);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null) return null;
        return (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Bootstrap:

```
public static void Bootstrap()
        {
            RouteConfigurator.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(IoC.Container));
            WindsorConfigurator.Configure();
        .
        .
         }
```

IoC:

```
public static class IoC
    {
        private static readonly object LockObj = new object();

        private static IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        public static IWindsorContainer Container
        {
            get { return container; }

            set
            {
                lock (LockObj)
                {
                    container = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public static T Resolve<T>()
        {
            return container.Resolve<T>();
        }

        public static object Resolve(Type type)
        {
            return container.Resolve(type);
        }
    }
```

WindsorRegistrar:

```
public class WindsorRegistrar
{

    public static void RegisterSingleton(Type interfaceType, Type implementationType)
    {
    IoC.Container.Register(Component.For(interfaceType).ImplementedBy(implementationType).LifeStyle.Singleton);
    }

    public static void Register(Type interfaceType, Type implementationType)
    {
    IoC.Container.Register(Component.For(interfaceType).ImplementedBy(implementationType).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
    }

    public static void RegisterAllFromAssemblies(string a)
    {
    IoC.Container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed(a).Pick().WithService.FirstInterface().LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}
```

HELP PLEASE ?

Comment: You didn't register the `WindsorControllerFactory` in the container. That's probably causing you this trouble.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Nuget package that makes Windsor integration into MVC application friction-less.

```
PM> Install-Package Castle.Windsor.Web.Mvc
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't spot any mistake at the first sight... But for sure your plumbing is redundant... Keept it simple as per windsor [tutorial](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-intro.md)